# How to test mapStateToProps using React Redux and Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

When I create a test for my connected React component where I want to test the mapStateToProps logic I run into a problem which I'm not sure how to solve.

Error message

```
Expected: 1
Received: undefined

  24 |     it('should show previously rolled value', () => {
  25 |         // test that the state values were correctly passed as props
> 26 |         expect(wrapper.props().lastRolledNumber).toBe(1);
```

When I check the wrapper.props() it only returns the store object and no properties.

To make sure it's not my code I have found an example that should work to simplify it, but I get the same problem when using that exact version in my app (option #2, https://jsramblings.com/2018/01/15/3-ways-to-test-mapStateToProps-and-mapDispatchToProps.html)

I think it might have to do with the React 16+ version, which I found mentioned here: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/props.html

> .props() => Object
>
> Returns the props object for the root node of the wrapper. It must be
>   a single-node wrapper. This method is a reliable way of accessing the
>   props of a node; wrapper.instance().props will work as well, but in
>   React 16+, stateless functional components do not have an instance.
>   See .instance() => ReactComponent

Does anyone know how to test this in a good way to see that the logic is working as expected without exporting the private mapStateToProps function directly?

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Component 1 - "Base component"
// Exporting it is a good practice for testing its own logic
export const Dice = ({ lastRolledNumber, onRollDice }) => (
    <div>        
        <p>The last rolled number was {lastRolledNumber}.</p>
        <button onClick={onRollDice}>Roll dice</button>
    </div>
);

Dice.propTypes = {
    lastRolledNumber: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onRollDice: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    lastRolledNumber: state.lastRolledNumber
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onRollDice: () => dispatch({ type: 'ROLL_DICE' })
});

// Component 2 - Container component
// Export it as a default export
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dice);
```

Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import '../test-config'; // Setup Enzyme & Adapter

import DiceContainer from './Dice';

// Create the mock store
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const mockStore = configureMockStore();

describe('Dice', () => {
    let wrapper, store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const initialState = {
            lastRolledNumber: 1
        };
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        // Shallow render the container passing in the mock store
        wrapper = shallow(
            <DiceContainer store={store} />
        );
    });

    it('should show previously rolled value', () => {
        // test that the state values were correctly passed as props
        expect(wrapper.props().lastRolledNumber).toBe(1);
    });

    it('should roll the dice again when button is clicked', () => {
        // test that the component events dispatch the expected actions 
        wrapper.simulate('rollDice');

        const actions = store.getActions();
        expect(actions).toEqual([ { type: 'ROLL_DICE' } ]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to call [.dive()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) method so that you can get the `Dice` component rather than the `DiceContainer` component which is wrapped by the `connect` HOC of `react-redux` module.

Short answer:

```js
wrapper = shallow(<DiceContainer store={store} />).dive();
```

A Completed working example:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export const Dice = ({ lastRolledNumber, onRollDice }) => (
  <div>
    <p>The last rolled number was {lastRolledNumber}.</p>
    <button onClick={onRollDice}>Roll dice</button>
  </div>
);

Dice.propTypes = {
  lastRolledNumber: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onRollDice: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  lastRolledNumber: state.lastRolledNumber,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onRollDice: () => dispatch({ type: 'ROLL_DICE' }),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dice);
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import DiceContainer from '.';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

describe('Dice', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const initialState = {
      lastRolledNumber: 1,
    };
    store = mockStore(initialState);
    wrapper = shallow(<DiceContainer store={store} />).dive();
  });

  it('should show previously rolled value', () => {
    expect(wrapper.props().lastRolledNumber).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should roll the dice again when button is clicked', () => {
    wrapper.simulate('rollDice');
    const actions = store.getActions();
    expect(actions).toEqual([{ type: 'ROLL_DICE' }]);
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59771991/index.test.jsx (9.645s)
  Dice
    ✓ should show previously rolled value (19ms)
    ✓ should roll the dice again when button is clicked (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.505s
```

Test coverage html report:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You saved me, was struggling with this for a while... Interesting that I missed the .dive() part. Added it and now it works for me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to write the test with render by this -

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {
    screen, cleanup, render,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const store = configureMockStore()({
    headerState: {
        showBack: false,
    },
});    
const mockProps = { ... };
describe('Component', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component {...mockProps} />
            </Provider>,
        );
    });
    afterAll(cleanup);

    test('Test', () => {
        screen.debug();
    });
});
```